# TWRP and LineageOS display flipped (180 degree rotation)

Tags: adb, screen, twrp, lineageos

I installed the latest version of TWRP and LineageOS on my BQ Aquaris U Plus and followed all [instructions](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/tenshi/install). Somehow, both TWRP (twrp-3.2.1-0-tenshi) and LineageOS (lineage-14.1-20180127-nightly-tenshi-signed) are flipped upside down.

As far as my search has led me, I have to edit the `/system/build.prop` and add the line

```
ro.sf.hwrotation=0
```

However, I am not able to push the file back to my phone. Nor am I able to edit the file on the device itself.

I am using the following code (Linux Mint):

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
sudo adb root
sudo adb devices
sudo adb remount
sudo nano build.prop 
sudo adb push build.prop /system
```

After that, adb does not seem to respond (empty line).

Am I missing something? Is there any possibility to fix this issue?

Comment: Is your ADB server running in insecure mode (i.e. as root – that is, when you run `adb shell` you get an `#` at the prompt immediately)? Because if not, you cannot simply push a file to `/system` as you don't have the required privileges. Though that should throw an error instead of giving an empty line.

Comment: @beeshyams That's a good call, but in this case I think the problem of editing `build.prop` is more generally applicable.

Comment: It actually did work to edit the build.prop when being in twrp. And the problem of the flipped screen was solved by flashing the firmware as provided by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, this was asked a long time ago... but, for future reference:

The problem seems to be the phone's firmware. The original stock ROM is still based on Android M ("Marshmallow"), but the current versions of LineageOS are based on Android N ("Nougat"). Apparently this is a problem, because between Android M and N, some things in the phone's firmware changed, causing the screen to be upside down. Flashing a new LineageOS, however, does not update the phone's firmware.

Update: As @loki mentioned in a comment, using the BQ Firmware Flash Tool is a convenient way to revert to the stock ROM and to update to the newest version. Afterwards, LineageOS can be installed as usual. I first assumed it would only be for Windows, but there is also a version for Ubuntu in the zip file.

My solution was:

1. Flash back the stock ROM with fastboot. Note: It doesn't work with TWRP; the zip file needs to be extracted. It contains a script which flashes all parts of the phone's software.
2. Use the stock ROM's updater to update to the newest version. This usually takes 2 update steps (probably because of the switch to Android N).
3. Start over with flashing TWRP. At this point, the screen orientation should be correct in TWRP.
4. Flash LineageOS with TWRP.

One final note: My phone needed a full data wipe in order to get rid of the disk encryption. The phone can be encrypted afterwards from within LineageOS, however, the original encryption from the stock ROM could not be decrypted correctly.

Comment: I did manage to use bq's firmware updater. Afterwards everything worked just fine. Perhaps you add this to the answer. Thanks for leaving this solution for future users.